# Fastest way to download large files from AWS EC2 EBS

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, file-transfer

Suppose I have a couple of terabytes worth of data files that have accumulated on an EC2 instance's block storage.

What would be the most efficient way of downloading them to a local machine? `scp`? `ftp`? `nfs`? `http`? `rsync`? Going through an intermediate `s3` bucket? Torrent via multiple machines? Any special tools or scripts out there for this particular problem?

Comment: For sufficiently large data sets, the fastest and cheapest way is to physically ship storage media.  See [AWS Snowball](https://aws.amazon.com/snowball/).

Comment: True, although I had a feeling that this service is more useful when the data goes into petabytes, where the time to ship a physical drive becomes actually comparable with the time to transfer over internet. A terabyte or so is probably still not *that* much. None the less, the choice of a protocol, it seems, may turn a several hour transfer into a several day one and vice-versa, hence this question.

Comment: It is still relevant for 10TB.  Look at your bandwidth costs for transferring 10TB out, and then how long will it take to move the data at, say, 100 Mb/s.  A 10TB drive sent by FedEx has amazing bandwidth and the FedEx bill is small for the bandwidth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please follow these rules:

- Move as one file, tar everything into a single archive file.
- Create S3 bucket in the same region as your EC2/EBS.
- Use [AWS CLI S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html) command to upload file to S3 bucket.
- Use AWS CLI to pull the file to your local or wherever another storage is.

This will be the easiest and most efficient way for you.

Answer (score 5):

As I did not really receive a convincing answer, I decided to make a small measurement myself. Here are the results I got:

[image]

More details [here](http://fouryears.eu/2017/05/02/the-file-download-problem/).

Comment: It is hard to add something to your own answer. Thanks for findings. I would only mention that in case you have *many* small files, you might want to investigate downloading in parallel to fully utilize available bandwidth. But if they are big files, it won't help as much due to less overhead.

Answer (score 2):

Some more info about this usecase is needed. I hope below concepts are helpfull:

- **HTTP** - fast, easy to implement, versatile and has small overhead.
- **Resilio** (formerly BitTorrent Sync) - fast, easy to deploy, decentralized, and secure. Can handle transfer interruptions. Works if both endpoints are behind NAT.
- **rsync** - old school and well known solution. Can resume transfer and fast in syncing big amounts of data.
- **Upload to S3 and get from there** - Upload to S3 is fast. Next You can use HTTP(S) or BitTorrent to get data localy.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what additional info I could provide. The question is simply about which method would be the fastest one in general, assuming I am ready to spend some hours for setting up the system.

I do not think that this answer helps me, though. For example, if I set up HTTP, I presume I'd need to download in parallel? How would it compare to downloading from S3 in parallel or rsync? As for BitTorrent, would I need to set up additional machines to replicate the data before downloading for it to make any sense?

Comment: In general, it seems hard to believe that there are really no good standard answer to a question "how to download files from a remote network" in the year 2017.

Comment: Well, "most efficient" is not a clearly defined criteria. All of mentioned solutions are efficient, while being different. For Resilio, no additional stuff, just a client on both sides.

Comment: By efficient I assume the total time needed to complete the transfer (assuming no bandwidth limitations on the receiving size and a reasonable budget).

Comment: Would Resilio know how to max out my incoming bandwidth? Is it better than rsync in this respect? Would an intermediate S3 storage step speed things up?

Comment: YMMV. DO You think someone would invent different technologies if all of them works equally well in all conditions and use cases?

Comment: I think that protocols are invented with various purposes in mind. For example, HTTP is invented (originally) for single-request single-file downloads. RSync is made for fast incremental synchronization. Torrent is invented for parallel downloads from multiple peers. S3 is invented as a cloud product, etc.
Of all technologies I know about, FTP was probably specifically invented as a dedicated file transfer tool, yet, paradoxically, in my experience it has always worked worse than HTTP. It may be the case that I'm simply not using it correctly, though. Hence the question here.

Comment: Of course I understand that "my mileage may vary", the question is what would be my best bet at maximizing this mileage without delving into research of my own.

Comment: With precisement to Your reqirements, all above solutions are most efficient.

Comment: I would disagree with that (see my measurement chart in a separate answer below).